# How to conver Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How can I can I convert this SQL query to LINQ?

```
select 
    c.Name as 'Name', s.Status 
from 
    (select 
         *, 
         row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by Date desc) rn
     from 
         CustomerStatus) detail
inner join 
    Status s on detail.Status = s.Id
inner join
    Customers c on detail.CustomerId = c.Id
where 
    detail.rn = 1
```

I am unable to convert this SQL to linq - how can I do this?

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Comment: Your title says "convert LINQ to SQL" but your question provides SQL and says you want to convert it to LINQ. Please make your title consistent. And I agree with Gert - you need to make an attempt here.

Comment: https://sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try (`ctx` is your database context):

```
ctx.CustomerStatus
  .GroupBy(cs => cs.CustomerId)
  .Select(gr => gr.OrderByDescending(cs => cs.Date).First())
  .Join(ctx.Status, cs => cs.Status, st => st.Id, (cs, st) => new {cs.CustomerId, Status = st})
  .Join(ctx.Customers, a => a.CustomerId, c => c.Id, (a, c) => new {a.Status.Status, c.Name});
```

Comment: @Micheal - This query hits database for 3 times as it is seen on profiler. I get the result as desired but the problem is that this query filtering the data in memory. Is there any other efficient way to do this...

Comment: @ChrisHadfield I think it's not a problem, since anyway, the data will be fetched from databse and .NET is using connection pool, so there shouldn't be aproblem.